# Display matrices of equal width but unequal lengths together

Tags: matrix

I have multiple tables, each two columns, but of various numbers of rows. How can I display them in a format similar to `TableForm` but next to each other for easy comparison?

Here are two example tables that I am dealing with:

```
ptFeOphys = DeleteCases[ptFeO, {p_, t_} /; T[p] > t]
{{{38, 1660}, {38, 1670}, {38, 1680}, {38, 1690}, {38, 1700}, {38, 
1710}, {39, 1640}, {39, 1650}, {39, 1660}, {39, 1670}, {39, 
1680}, {39, 1690}, {39, 1700}, {39, 1710}, {39, 1720}, {39, 
1730}, {39, 1740}, {39, 1750}, {40, 1620}, {40, 1630}, {40, 
1640}, {40, 1650}, {40, 1740}, {40, 1750}, {40, 1760}, {40, 
1770}, {40, 1780}, {41, 1610}, {41, 1620}, {41, 1630}, {41, 
1780}, {41, 1790}, {41, 1800}, {42, 1610}, {42, 1620}, {42, 
1810}, {42, 1820}, {42, 1830}, {43, 1600}, {43, 1610}, {43, 
1830}, {43, 1840}, {43, 1850}, {44, 1850}, {44, 1860}, {44, 
1870}, {45, 1870}, {45, 1880}, {46, 1890}, {46, 1900}, {47, 
1910}, {47, 1920}, {48, 1930}, {48, 1940}, {49, 1940}, {49, 
1950}, {50, 1960}, {50, 1970}, {51, 1980}, {52, 1990}, {52, 2000}}

ptSiO2phys = DeleteCases[ptSiO2, {p_, t_} /; T[p] > t]
{{8, 1880}, {12, 1930}, {16, 1980}, {53, 1690}, {53, 1700}, {53, 
1710}, {53, 1720}, {53, 1730}, {53, 1740}, {53, 1750}, {54, 
1690}, {54, 1770}, {54, 1780}, {55, 1800}, {56, 1820}, {57, 
1850}, {58, 1870}, {59, 1890}, {62, 1940}, {63, 1960}, {64, 1980}}
```

Thank you!

Comment: For matrices `a` and `b` you could try `Row[{MatrixForm[a], MatrixForm[b]}]`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher It worked! Thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: also: `TableForm[{TableForm /@ {a, b}}, TableAlignments -> Top]`

Comment: Advice: post a _minimal_ example. All your code could be replaced with something similar to `a = RandomReal[1,{10,15}]; b = RandomReal[1, {8,15}]`, much more readable and copy-pastable.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have the following two matrices of unequal length

```
SeedRandom[0];
mat1=RandomReal[1,{7,2}];
mat2=RandomReal[1,{10,2}];
```

The following command perhaps does what you want,

```
TableForm[Transpose[PadRight[{mat1,mat2}]]]
```